# Get start process after reconnect the internet

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am running a service from a .exe file, when I test this system, I removed the internet connection and after some time plugged in, the internet is connecting, but my process is not connecting. In the command prompt it is showing connection problem.

How can I restart my process automatically after get the internet connection ?

Advice me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of restarting the process once the internet is connected again, just let the process run on a schedule, and once it needs to run, check for internet connection. If there is an internet connection, do your thing, else end the current run gracefully.

in pseudocode:

```
public void StartOfMethodThatRequiresInternet(){
    if(!requiredAddress.IsAvailable()){
        return;
    }
    DoTheRestOfTheProgram();
}
```

Schedule this function to run however often you need it, through the service or through the Windows Scheduler. It will automatically start and check if the website you need to access is available. if it is not available, it will automatically return.

To check if a website is available, issue a HttpWebRequest for the headers and check if the response code is OK. [Check if a url is reachable - Help in optimizing a Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378429/check-if-a-url-is-reachable-help-in-optimizing-a-class) explains how to do this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Timeout = 15000;
request.Method = "HEAD"; // As per Lasse's comment
try
{
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
    {
        return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
}
catch (WebException)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: sorry , i for get to share some thing, that is when this process running i am writing the data in o a text file in my c:\ drive.

Comment: @user3463529 That doesn't matter for checking your internet connection. Just check for the internet connection when you think is the best time to do so, whether that's before you start writing the file or after.

Comment: sorry , i for get to share some thing, that is when this process running i am writing the data in o a text file in my c:\ drive, and from this .txt file i am reading the data in to a array and based on that date i am updating other tables in mysql. the service fetching the data from Sql server. in this situation i removed the internet connection and plugged in after some time.Then in the command prompt i am getting this message 'The process cannot access the .txt file because it is being used by another one', then there is no updates in my table in mysql.Advise me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: @user3463529 ah, that's another problem. What happens is your process doesn't close the connection to the file after losing internet connection. Read up on `using` statements for entering data into the file and gracefully close the file when you lose your internet connection.